# PostgreSQL: order by sum of computed values

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, null

I have a table `tips` that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tips
(
  tip_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  tip text NOT NULL,
  author text NOT NULL,
  post_date bigint NOT NULL,
  likers character varying(16)[],
  dislikers character varying(16)[],
  likes integer NOT NULL,
  dislikes integer NOT NULL,
  abuse_history character varying(16)[]
);
```

I need to get the tips based on popularity, with the definition of popularity being:
 **likes - dislikes - (size(abuse_history)*5)**

The query below gives me the same results regardless of the sort order (ASC/DESC).

```
select * from tips order by (likes - dislikes - (array_length(abuse_history,1) * 5)) ASC limit 2147483647 offset 0
```

**EDIT**

I inserted 3 records that have the following values:
1) 1 like, 0 dislikes, 0 abuse complaints
2) 0 likes, 1 dislike, 0 abuse complaints
3) 0 likes, 0 dislikes, 0 abuse...

Regardless of the sort order (ASC/DESC), I get the following order:
{3, 1, 2}

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: * Clarification - it gives the same sort order, with no regards to the desired sort key; looks random.

Comment: @JackManey - I need the results sorted based on the above logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this:

```
SELECT array_length('{}'::character varying(16)[], 1);  -- null
```

Output is `null` for an empty array. Also, your `abuse_history` can be `null` itself. So you need something like this:

```sql
SELECT tip_id
     , likes
     , dislikes
     , (likes - dislikes - COALESCE(array_upper(abuse_history,1) * 5,0)) as pop
     , (likes - dislikes - array_upper(abuse_history,1) * 5) AS fail_pop
FROM   tips
ORDER  BY pop DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UP1hgwom)

Sample output:

```
 tip_id | likes | dislikes | pop | fail_pop
--------+-------+----------+-----+----------
      1 |     1 |        0 |   1 |
      2 |     1 |        0 |   1 |
      4 |     0 |        0 |   0 |
      3 |     0 |        1 |  -1 |
      5 |     1 |        0 | -14 |      -14
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I tried this `select * from tips order by (likes - dislikes - COALESCE(array_length(abuse_history,1), 0) * 5) ASC` to no success.

Comment: @vivri: maybe you try my demo and report back if you get different results. Also, you have **ASC** in your query, but I assume you want DESC.

Comment: Thanks, your tip to use coalesce works! The reason it didn't work the first time has other reasons :))

Answer (score 2):

In order to debug this, put the same expression of the `ORDER BY` clause into the `SELECT` part. Then examine the results - are they really what you expect?

```
select *, (likes - dislikes - (array_length(abuse_history,1) * 5)) 
from tips 
order by (likes - dislikes - (array_length(abuse_history,1) * 5)) ASC 
limit 2147483647 offset 0
```

Oh, and BTW, strip that silly `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` thing.

Comment: note that you can just change the order to "order by 2" to order by the second returned column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t2.*
from ( select t1.*,
       (likes - dislikes - (array_length(abuse_history,1) * 5)) as popularity
       from tips t1) t2
order by popularity;
```

Edit: The above usually works (at least with Oracle). Maybe the below variation that uses the `With` clause will avoid the error.

```
WITH popularity_query as
     ( select t.*,
              (likes - dislikes - (array_length(abuse_history, 1) * 5)) as popularity
       from tips t)
select * from popularity_query order by popularity
```

Comment: I tried this: `select * from ( select t.*, likes - dislikes - (array_length(abuse_history,1) * 5)) as popularity from tips t) order by (popularity) DESC ...` and got this error: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"
  Position: 99`

Comment: @vivri: I suggested an edit to dave's answer that attaches a name to the subquery, which should fix the syntax error. However, the subquery is not needed for the problem at hand.

Comment: Although the subquery is not really necessary, as stated by @Erwin, it allows for a simpler order by clause. I've always hated repeating computations in an order by clause.

Comment: Just do order by colnum where colnum is the number of the returned column, i.e. order by 2 ASC